# Is there a built-in way to extract bibliography items (author(s), title, etc) from image?

Tags: citation-management

I have read the (quite recent) [Seeking the Productive Life: Some Details of My Personal Infrastructure](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2019/02/seeking-the-productive-life-some-details-of-my-personal-infrastructure/) and in particular the section "Archiving & Searching"; it seems to me that Stephen Wolfram spends almost his time in the Mathematica computing environment and so, is there any built-in way to extract bibliography items (author(s), title, etc) from an image? I mean an image of a scanned book or paper.

I see here https://wolfram.com/xid/0b0kqvyhnry-dlrt3u something that looks like what I have in mind but
`TextRecognize` seems to me quite general, just a basic block to answer my question.

I see this question [Extract bibliography from a PDF document](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96523/extract-bibliography-from-a-pdf-document) but the answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96525/76297 did not seem to generalize so well according to comment [Extract bibliography from a PDF document](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96523/extract-bibliography-from-a-pdf-document#comment261348_96525)

Comment: No, there's is no dedicated function for text-recognizing specifically, e.g., the author from an image. `TextRecognize` can help you extract the text and `TextCases` can help you organise the extracted contents (see also [Text Content Types](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TextContentTypes.html)), but you're going to have to do some work on top of that.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/12/launching-version-12-2-of-wolfram-language-mathematica-228-new-functions-and-much-more/ at *Importing PDF*... it seems not too far :-)